# Guaranteed order of groupingBy aggregate Map in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am using a `groupingBy` and then `aggregate` to process a list of items and group them into pairs. The order of the input list is important, and the resulting list should also be ordered.

`aggregate` returns a `Map` indicating that the processing order is not preserved.

Example:

```kotlin
    data class Foo(val a: Int, val b: String)

    val r1 = Foo(1, "a")
    val r2 = Foo(1, "b")
    val r3 = Foo(2, "c")
    val r4 = Foo(2, "d")
    val r5 = Foo(2, "e")
    val records = listOf(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5)

    val result = records.groupingBy { it.a }
        .aggregate { _, acc: Pair<Int, List<String>>?, element, _ ->
            if (acc == null) {
                element.a to listOf(element.b)
            } else {
                acc.first to acc.second + element.b
            }
        }.values.toList()

    println(result)
```

Returns `[(1, [a, b]), (2, [c, d, e])]` - which is the correct order, but is it *guaranteed*?

PLEASE NOTE that this is a simple example that may be sorted by `a` - but that is NOT the solution, as the records sorting is provided by the user of the function.

Comment: If it's not in the documentation of the function (which [it isn't](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/aggregate.html)), then it's not guaranteed. They theoretically could change the underlying implementation.

Comment: @Tenfour04 although if we know the Kotlin `mapOf` is _sorted_ (that is documented), we might assume that it is kind of documented, I guess....

Comment: Documentation of one function doesn't apply to other functions. That's not a guarantee.

Comment: Agree @Tenfour04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aggregate`'s documentation does not guarantee this, but `mutableMapOf`'s documentation does guarantee it. So I would use `aggregateTo(mutableMapOf()) { /*...*/ }` to future-proof your code. The fact that they don't guarantee it means either they forgot to, or they deliberately want to keep open the option of switching the underlying implementation for performance in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that the Pairs of the aggregation result are ordered, you could do:

```
fun main() {
    data class Foo(val a: Int, val b: String)

    val r1 = Foo(2, "a")
    val r2 = Foo(2, "b")
    val r3 = Foo(1, "c")
    val r4 = Foo(1, "d")
    val r5 = Foo(2, "e")
    val records = listOf(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5)

    val result = records.groupingBy { it.a }
        .aggregate { _, acc: Pair<Int, List<String>>?, element, _ ->
            if (acc == null) {
                element.a to listOf(element.b)
            } else {
                acc.first to acc.second + element.b
            }
        }.values.sortedBy {it.first}.toList()

    println(result)
}
```

This would output `[(1, [c, d]), (2, [a, b, e])]`.

Comment: That is out of option, sorry. I just used a simple example, but sorting is defined by whoever sends the records. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the original list you could sort the list after grouping using [the index of](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of-first.html) the elements in the original list.

```kotlin
data class Foo(val a: Int, val b: String)
  
fun main() {

  val r1 = Foo(2, "a")
  val r2 = Foo(2, "b")
  val r3 = Foo(1, "c")
  val r4 = Foo(1, "d")
  val r5 = Foo(2, "e")
  val records = listOf(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5)

  // shuffle the records - just to test to make sure the sorting works
  val shuffledRecords = records.shuffled()

  val result = shuffledRecords.groupingBy { it.a }
    .aggregate { _, acc: Pair<Int, List<String>>?, element, _ ->
      if (acc == null) {
        element.a to listOf(element.b)
      } else {
        acc.first to acc.second + element.b
      }
    }
    .values
    // after grouping, ensure the values are sorted using the ordering from the original list
    .map { (k, values) -> k to values.sortedBy { value -> records.indexOfFirst { it.b == value } } }

  println(result)
}
```

Even though the records were shuffled, the output is still ordered

```
[(1, [c, d]), (2, [a, b, e])]
```